# Robot tires slipping in Gazebo Ignition. Odometry going wrong hence

Tags: gazebo, odometry, differential-drive, ignition-fortress

I am simulating a 4 wheel differential drive robot in Gazebo Fortress. However, my friction settings seem to be incorrect because my tires slip a lot more than the robot turns and hence my odometry has gone awry which further messes up my SLAM.
For example if my robot turns around ~ 30 degrees (by visual inspection) the odometry reports that it has gone beyond ~90 degrees. Wheels are slipping too much.

Here is the collision tag from my wheel xacro :

```
<collision>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode>
                <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
              </ode>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>1000000</mu>
                <mu2>1000000</mu2>
                <kp value="1000000000000.0" />
                <kd value="1000000000000.0" />
                <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
                <slip1>0.01</slip1>
                <slip2>0.01</slip2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
```

Here's the collision tag from the ground plane of my world.

```
<collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode>
                <min_depth>0.005</min_depth>
              </ode>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>100000</mu>
                <mu2>10000</mu2>
                <slip1>0.001</slip1>
                <slip2>0.001</slip2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
```

I am certain the problem is with these setings, though suggestions pointing elsewhere are welcome. I am at my wit's end trying to figure these out, and any insight in this would be tremendously helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: I don' think there is any relation between odometry report and tire slipping.

Comment: Can the Wheel Slip Plugin help?

Comment: My odometry is going wrong because the encoders report the wheel rotations which gives us odometry right?